# what is the best to read calendar event instance for specific date period for a specific calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, android-calendar, recurring-events, rrule

I am trying to read all instances of events for a specific calendar and a specific period. Here is my problem.

(1) I read all instances of events for the specific period, then I query an event for each event instance to see if the event instance belong to the calendar. It is quite slow.

(2) I read all events for the specific period, then read all instances of the recurring event. I will miss the events started prior to my date range.

Any suggestions are welcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for #2 - in your date query you should use 'between' start end and end date then you will not miss events started prior to your date range.